# Excel 2010 need help transferring matching values between two sheets

Tags: worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2010

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jRASz.png)

I need to perform inventory costing for everything we have in the production warehouse. The issue is we have an old inventory sheet that has over 44K parts listed with their associated costs, but most of these parts are no longer used. I manually created a new sheet that only lists the items we have in the back, but now I have the issue of matching their associated costs...

Basically what I'm asking is how can I have Excel look at the values in one column & find the matching value in another column, then transfer over the cost from a separate 3rd column? Any help would be greatly applicated, I've had no luck with my search engine results.

EDIT: I have been trying to use the Vlookup function but I keep returning errors. I have added a screen shot to help with visuals. Basically I'm trying to use the value in column b, compare it J & if it matches, return the value in K to column D

Edit #2: included a new screen shot with formula included. Column J&K are 29K each & I need the formula to reference the whole thing but I think its only looking at the last cell?

Thank you thank you thank you in advance!

Comment: please [edit] the post to include the VLOOKUP formula you tried that returns errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[VLOOKUP](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vlookup-function-0bbc8083-26fe-4963-8ab8-93a18ad188a1) format is:

> =VLOOKUP(What you want to look up, where you want to look for it, the column number in the range containing the value to return, return an Approximate or Exact match – indicated as 1/TRUE, or 0/FALSE)

for your instance:

```
=VLOOKUP(B6,$J:$K,2,FALSE)
```

Comment: Thank you for the help Scott, I truly applicate your time!  It looks like some of the cells returned correctly but some did not? for example D6 should have returned 0.62 but i got N/A? I will edit the originally post to include a new screen shot. thank you again brother, your a god send!

Comment: Currently the `False` means it is looking for an exact match.  If an exact match is not found then it returns the error.  If you want a relative search change the `False` to `True` and make sure the data is sorted ascending on column J.  If you want exact and it is returning an error where you feel it should not, then check the data.  Exact is exactly that.  The values in the cells must be exactly the same and sometimes there are spaces or other non printable items in one or both of the cells that may throw off the exactness.

Comment: That's exactly what the issue is! Shoot I just noticed there were 7 spaces after the number in column J, is there a way to get around that error? The number is a perfect match but the spaces are causing the formula to throwing errors. 

I found your PayPal link by the way ;) Ill shoot you a couple cases of coke zero once we are done here.

Comment: is there a way to remove any spaces from column j in one fell swoop?

Comment: Best thing to do is to put `=TRIM(CLEAN(SUBSTITUTE(J6,Char(164),"")))` in a free column and copy down the whole dataset.  Then copy paste special values only back into J.

Comment: And you do not need to buy me any coke zeros, glad to help.

Comment: Oh you gosh Scott you are a legend! I cant express how grateful I am for you!!! A long time ago I said technology is modern day magic & you sir are a wizard of the highest order! Grand wizard, Arch Magi, king of technology, whatever title you want its yours! You just crafted a spell to magically pull ALL the data I needed & it saved me HOURS of manually using ctrl F to search each one up individually. Thank you for sticking around to see me through!!!!

Comment: By chance is there a way to do this & keep the source data on a separate sheet? I just noticed i have to copy the data into each sheet individually & the file is going to be massive

Comment: Sorry was in a meeting.  To deal with the data in another sheet one simply has to add the sheet name in front the reference: `=VLOOKUP(B6,'Sheet4'!$J:$K,2,FALSE)`